# SQL Server remove duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I looked for similar questions and could not find a solution.

Here is my data :

```
repair_id   car_license   repair_date   mechanic_id
---------------------------------------------------
1           111            1/9/2015       9
2           111            3/3/2015       9
3           111            7/7/2015       9
4           111            7/7/2015       9
5           111            7/7/2015       9
6           222            2/1/2015       9
7           222            4/3/2015       9
8           333            11/7/2015      8
```

I am trying to select car licenses within a date range ex 2/1/2015 to 8/1/2015 and mechanic_id 9.

Even though car_license 111 for repair_id 1 is not within 2/1/2015 to 8/1/2015, it should still be returned because car_license 111 also has repair_id 2 & 3 within the date range.

I also must remove the duplicate rows 4 and 5 from the result set

```
repair_id   car_license   repair_date  mechanic_id
---------------------------------------------------
1           111            1/9/2015     9
2           111            3/3/2015     9
3           111            7/7/2015     9
6           222            2/1/2015     9
7           222            4/3/2015     9
```

I tried this but am not sure how to continue

```
select 
    repair_id, car_license, repair_date
from 
    car_table
where 
    repair_date between '2/1/2015' and '8/1/2015'
    and mechanic_id = 9
```

but how to remove the duplicate rows in that code?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is your date `MM/DD/YYYY`?

Comment: my date is smalldatetime format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you don't need a `DELETE` statement, but just a simple `SELECT`. This might help you:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY car_license, repair_date ORDER BY repair_id)
    FROM car_table ct1
    WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM car_table ct2
        WHERE
            ct2.car_license = ct1.car_license
            AND ct2.mechanic_id = ct2.mechanic_id
            AND ct2.repair_date BETWEEN '20150201' AND '20150801'
            AND ct2.mechanic_id = 9
    )
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Do we really need `mechanic_id` in `PARTITION BY`

Comment: Not really, since OP is filtering it. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: if i wanted to further select by the number of non duplicate entries, how could that be possible?  For example 111 minus the duplicates appears three times and 222 appears two times, should i just change  this:  'SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1'  to this:   'SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1 and count (cte.car_license = 3)'  for 111  and ' . . count(cte.car_license = 2)' for 222?    thx

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function to identify the duplicates

Try this

```
;WITH cte AS
(
select row_number()over(partition by car_license,repair_date order by repair_id) RN,*
From car_table
where repair_date between '2/1/2015' and '8/1/2015'
and mechanic_id = 9
)
DELETE FROM cte where rn > 1
```

To check the records which will be deleted you can run the below uery and check

```
;WITH cte AS
(
select row_number()over(partition by car_license,repair_date order by repair_id) RN,*
From car_table
where repair_date between '2/1/2015' and '8/1/2015'
and mechanic_id = 9
)
SELECT * FROM cte where rn > 1
```

Comment: this seems like it will delete everything where the count is greater than one:   DELETE FROM cte where rn > 1      It should only remove the duplicate rows

Comment: @JamesRodriguez - No it won't. Check the update in my answer